# Gridview multiselect checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

[image]

mentioned in the above image

Friends have a WinForm as above, and then right-click checkbox when deleting the selected rows in the GridView what I can do.

thanks.

Comment: You want to delete a checked row ?

Comment: yes ı want checkhed row delete gridview and database

Comment: What's the datasource of GridView ?

Comment: devexpress grdicontrol and database sql server linq to sql

Comment: I added the above screenshots

Comment: is the code in the answer work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete selected rows from GridView with this code :

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
    GridView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as GridView;
    view.DeleteSelectedRows();
    //DB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

or also with code :

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as GridView;
    if (view == null || view.SelectedRowsCount == 0) return;

    DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[view.SelectedRowsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < view.SelectedRowsCount; i++)
        rows[i] = view.GetDataRow(view.GetSelectedRows()[i]);

    view.BeginSort();

    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
         row.Delete();
    }
    finally
    {
        view.EndSort();
    }
}
```

You can call your delete method in loop `for`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    MyDeleteMethod(row["ColumnNameId"]);
    //You must cast row["ColumnNameId"] to type of parameter
    row.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GridView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as GridView;
            foreach (var rowHandle in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
            {
               //you have now dataRow checked for deleting from your database
                DataRow dw = view.GetDataRow(rowHandle);

                //This line for delete the checked rows from your Grid view
                view.DeleteRow(rowHandle);

            }
        }
```

For more informations about How Delete Selected Data Rows ,visit this [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A234)